# How to share Tomboy-ng notes between two users on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, sync, tomboy

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD. Additionally, I have a second HDD.
I created two users.

- User1 as admin
- User2

I would like to install tomboy-ng for both users.
I downloaded `tomboy-ng_0.27-0_amd64.deb`.
And I tried to install it.

My questions are:

1. How to completely remove tomboy and settings and configs. I ask because I removed and I installed again and tomboy remember my paths.
2. How to configure `tomboy-ng` for both users. I would like to have sync function between two users.
   I thought about new directory on HDD drive.

Can someone help me?
Because now I get the message:

> ```
> Unable to open file "/tmp/tomboy-ng".
> ```

Comment: What do you mean with "sync function"? That both users work on the same notes? If they don't at the same time, it will not be a problem. If, however, you expect them to modify the notes at the same time, it will not be possible. By the way, one question is *one* question on this site. If multiple questions, ask a new one.

Comment: I was thinking  about situation when user1 edit something and logout and next user2 login and have access to notes. I wont to answer on second question.

Comment: Better edit your question to put your question sharp. Will increase the chance of a good and specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

luki, this is probably a question better posted to the tomboy-ng issues page of github.  tomboy-ng is not an Ubuntu official package.

Anyway, yes, would work fine as long as you have a some shared diskspace between the two users. Create a directory somewhere and give both users write access to it. Set that dir as tomboy-ng's note location.  I might make that dir in /var/tomboy-ng, change its owner to one of the users and set its group to be one that both users are members of. If there is any change both users could be active at the same time, use file sync, leave each users notes in the default place and sync to that shared dir.

( and to remove all of tomboy-ng's content, the default place to store config is $HOME/.config/tomboy-ng and the default place for notes is $HOME/.local/share/tomboy-ng )